# Regex for three digit number range

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I validate given three digit number is in range by using regex. I need to validate number from 000 to 200.

I tried

```
(1[0-9][0-9]|200)
```

this regex but it is not validating 000, 001, 002..099 . I need to validated exactly three digit number starting from 000 to 200

Comment: Use [this Web site](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) to generate any such regex.

Comment: Did you try `[0-1][0-9][0-9]|200`?